# can't get the dynamic textfield value using Jquery

Tags: javascript

I can't get the dynamic textfield value. Please see the below my jquery code.

I added onclick event while creating the textfield for LandMark. Please see the below code.
I am always getting undefined. Please help me.

function dynamicEvent() {

```
     alert("dynamic event");
     $(document).ready(function(){
     alert("inside ajax --> dynamic");

     var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
     alert("table-->"+table);
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;         
     alert("rowCount-->"+rowCount);
     alert("value of rowCount"+rowCount);           
     var uniqueId;
     for (var i=rowCount;rowCount>7;i++){

        uniqueId = i;
        alert("inside for loop");
        alert("uniqueId-->"+uniqueId);

        var element = document.createElement("input");
        uniqueId=uniqueId-1;   

            element.id = "t02Travelfrom" +uniqueId;


            var tfrom=element.id; 

            alert("tfrom id-->"+tfrom);

            var t02Travelfrom=$("tfrom").val();

            alert(tfrom+"--value-->" +t02Travelfrom);

        }

     });

 }
```

Comment: Take a look here ;-) http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$("tfrom")` returning elements with tag `tfrom`

You need `$(tfrom)`. You don't need double quotas.

Comment: `tfrom` is an element id

Comment: yes i accept its id, now i removed and its working. thank you for your great help. thanks forum.

Comment: It couldn't work, can't understand why this answer was accepted

Comment: `tfrom` is not id, look at this `element.id = "t02Travelfrom" +uniqueId;` it says that `t02Travelfrom` following some id is element id, and `tfrom` is element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect selector:

```
var t02Travelfrom=$("tfrom").val();
```

change to:

```
var t02Travelfrom=$("#" + tfrom).val();
```